# viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind in UICollectionView returns nil and crashes app using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that is working correctly. However I am trying to add section headers programmatically and I am running into a crash which I can't figure out.

My Class for the header:

```
class EmbeddedSectionHeaderCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {

    weak var sectionHeaderLabel: UILabel!

}
```

My header class registration in ViewDidLoad

```
myCollection.register(EmbeddedSectionHeaderCollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "sectionHeader")
```

My header implementation for section size definition

```
    // header section size. needed for implementation. 
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.size.width, height:30.0)
    }
```

The viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind code

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        if let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "sectionHeader", for: indexPath) as? EmbeddedSectionHeaderCollectionReusableView {

            print("header should be showing")
            sectionHeader.sectionHeaderLabel.text = "Hello, World"
            return sectionHeader

        }

        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
```

The crash happens at "sectionHeader.sectionHeaderLabel.text = "Hello, World"" saying that sectionHeader is nil. My gut tells me it's because I am not initializing the header class correctly. Could that be it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add init

```
class EmbeddedSectionHeaderCollectionReusableView : UICollectionReusableView { 
  var sectionHeaderLabel: UILabel! 
  override init(frame: CGRect) { 
    super.init(frame: frame)  
    sectionHeaderLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))  
    self.addSubview(sectionHeaderLabel) 
 }
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much